# sending a list of images to Django REST framework - iOS Client

Tags: ios, django, rest, django-rest-framework, alamofire

Im trying to **send a list of images** from **iOS application** to a **Django REST** backend. This is the iOS Request using AlamoFire.

**iOS Code:**

```
let URL = "myURL"
        var imagesDictonaryList = [[String : AnyObject]]()
        var images = [UIImage]()
        for _ in 1...3 {
            images.append(UIImage(named: "profileImagePlaceholder")!)
        }
        //let imagesData = imagesToBase64(images)
        for index in 0..<3 {
            var myDictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
            myDictionary["name"] = "\(index)"
            myDictionary["image"] = images[index]
            imagesDictonaryList.append(myDictionary)
        }
        print(imagesDictonaryList)
        let parameters = [
            "title": "service 1 title",
            "description": "service 1 description",
            "price": "11",
            "images": imagesDictonaryList
        ]
        Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject]).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            if let dataString = String(data: response.data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                print(dataString)
            }
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }
```

**Server Code:**

**views.py**

```
class PredefinedServiceList(APIView):
    """
    List all Predefined Services, or create a new Predefined Service
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PredefinedServiceSerializer(data=request.POST)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ServiceImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        b64_text = validated_data.get('image', None)

        image_data = b64decode(b64_text)
        image_content = ContentFile(b"%s" % image_data, 'whatup.jpg')

        validated_data['image'] = image_content

        instance = ServiceImage.objects.create()
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = ServiceImage
        fields = ('image', 'name')


class PredefinedServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ServiceImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PredefinedService
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'images')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images_data = validated_data.pop('images')
        service = PredefinedService.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for image in images_data:
            new_image, created = ServiceImage.objects.get_or_create(name=image.get('name', None))
            new_image.image = image.get('image', None)

            new_image.save()

            service.images.add(new_image)
        return service
```

**models.py**

```
class ServiceImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="predefined", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=9001, null=True)

class PredefinedService(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default="untitled")
    description = models.TextField(default="No description available.")
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.000)
    images = models.ForeignKey(ServiceImage, null=True, blank=True)
```

The problem is that the images are not in the request.data in the code but all other information sent are there.

the images are just an empty list after the iOS Client request. and the HTML i get is "index out of range" when hard coding list[0] to see the first picture received.

what might the problem be in this code? how to solve it? and is there any better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Files can be accessed via

```
request.FILES
```

so you would have to change

```
serializer = PredefinedServiceSerializer(data=request.POST)
```

to

```
serializer = PredefinedServiceSerializer(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
```

But if you're using DRF higher than 3.0, then according to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#the-data-and-query_params-properties), the correct way to do this is using data attribute

```
serializer = PredefinedServiceSerializer(data=request.data)
```

Comment: appreciate your answer, but the problem is still presented even with the above changes.